# php merge array recursively with add if not exist on specific location

Tags: php, arrays, merge, position

i spend to much time in an array merge problem

i have two array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => zkd
    [1] => zklPoi
    [2] => interlocuteur
    [3] => moyenCom
    [4] => date
    [5] => action
    [6] => plan
    [7] => planUser
    [8] => planDate
    [9] => sql
    [10] => sqlUser
    [11] => sqlDate
    [12] => genreAction
    [13] => nameAction
    [14] => comment
    [15] => zk_remote
    [16] => zk_host
    [17] => zk_came
    [18] => zk_referrer
    [19] => zk_config
    [20] => zkm_date
    [21] => zkm_user
    [22] => zkc_date
    [23] => zkc_user
)
```

//**********************************************************************************

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [field] => zklPoi
            [text] => NÂ°Poi
            [required] => _R
            [input] => text
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [field] => Interlocuteur
            [text] => Interlocuteur
            [required] => _R
            [input] => text
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [field] => moyenCom
            [text] => Moyen de communication
            [required] => _R
            [input] => text
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [field] => date
            [text] => Date
            [required] => _R
            [input] => text
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [field] => action
            [text] => Action demandÃ©e
            [required] => _R
            [input] => text
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [field] => plan
            [text] => sur les plans
            [required] => _R
            [input] => text
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [field] => planUser
            [text] => destiner Ã 
            [required] => _R
            [input] => text
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [field] => planDate
            [text] => Date plan souhaitÃ©e
            [required] => _R
            [input] => text
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [field] => sql
            [text] => dans la Bdd
            [required] => _R
            [input] => text
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [field] => sqlUser
            [text] => destiner Ã 
            [required] => _R
            [input] => text
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [field] => sqlDate
            [text] => Date SQL souhaitÃ©e
            [required] => _R
            [input] => text
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [field] => nameAction
            [text] => Nom Action
            [required] => _F
            [input] => text
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [field] => comment
            [text] => Commentaire
            [required] => _F
            [input] => text
        )

)
```

i want to merge these arrays to output exactly this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [existField]=>zkd
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [existField]=>zklPoi
            [field] => zklPoi
            [text] => NÂ°Poi
            [required] => _R
            [input] => text
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [existField]=>Interlocuteur
            [field] => Interlocuteur
            [text] => Interlocuteur
            [required] => _R
            [input] => text
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [existField]=>moyenCom
            [field] => moyenCom
            [text] => Moyen de communication
            [required] => _R
            [input] => text
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [existField]=>date
            [field] => date
            [text] => Date
            [required] => _R
            [input] => text
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [existField]=>action
            [field] => action
            [text] => Action demandÃ©e
            [required] => _R
            [input] => text
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [existField]=>plan
            [field] => plan
            [text] => sur les plans
            [required] => _R
            [input] => text
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [existField]=>planUser
            [field] => planUser
            [text] => destiner Ã 
            [required] => _R
            [input] => select
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [existField]=>planDate
            [field] => planDate
            [text] => Date plan souhaitÃ©e
            [required] => _R
            [input] => text
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [existField]=>sql
            [field] => sql
            [text] => dans la Bdd
            [required] => _R
            [input] => text
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [existField]=>sqlUser
            [field] => sqlUser
            [text] => destiner Ã 
            [required] => _R
            [input] => select
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [existField]=>sqlDate
            [field] => sqlDate
            [text] => Date SQL souhaitÃ©e
            [required] => _R
            [input] => text
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [existField]=>genreAction
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [existField]=>nameAction
            [field] => nameAction
            [text] => Nom Action
            [required] => _F
            [input] => text
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [existField]=>comment
            [field] => comment
            [text] => Commentaire
            [required] => _F
            [input] => textarea
        )
    [15] => Array
        (
            [existField]=>zk_remote
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [existField]=>zk_host
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [existField]=>zk_came
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [existField]=>zk_referrer
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [existField]=>zk_config
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [existField]=>zkm_date
        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [existField]=>zkm_user
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [existField]=>zkc_date
        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [existField]=>zkc_user
        )


)
```

for use merged array:
i need to display where the "[required] => _R" in variables for use in script
like "implode(',',[field])"
i need to display all where isSet "[field] => anything" in variables for use in script
like: if[input]==text: "input type=[input] name=[field] placeholder=[text]"
      if[input]==textarea: "textarea name=[field] placeholder=[text] /textarea"
      if[input]==select: "select name=[field] /select"

Hope sombody can help me improve time
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this bit of code results in exactly the same output as you're expecting:

```
foreach ($array1 as $value1) {
    $found = 0;
    foreach ($array2 as $value2) {
        if ($value2['field'] == $value1) {
            $result[] = array(
                "existField" => $value1,
                "field" => $value2['field'],
                "text" => $value2['text'],
                "required" => $value2['required'],
                "input" => $value2['input']
            );
            $found = 1;
        }
    }
    if (!$found) {
        $result[] = array(
            "existField" => $value1
        );
    }
}
```

PHPFiddle Link: http://www.phpfiddle.org/main/code/j27g-bydk

Edit: updated the PHPFiddle link, as I had a typo in one of the arrays.

Comment: work fine for me, what about extract the desired data, like descibed, you can help me for this too?

Comment: I can't quite understand what are you trying to achieve there.

Comment: i want to make new array from this array created with your code where "[required] => _R" with all the keys and values, meens delete all where required is not set or value is not "_R"